# How can I make it so the baller/ball does not keep moving after it bounces?

Tags: unity, c#

I am pretty new to Unity so how I did it may not be the best way, but when the character jumps it is inconsistent. When I press the up arrow key really quickly and then stop the jump will be further than it is supposed to be and it starts to glide. I want all the jumps to be the same size and the player can't bounce again until it is on the ground. Also if I start playing to quickly within the first second or two the ball jumps really far but if I wait a couple seconds it bounce like normal.

Here is my code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour {   

    public float distance;      
    public float fspeed;
    public float uspeed;
    public float addToDistance;
    bool jumping = false;

    //PRIVATE
    private Rigidbody rigidBody;

    void Awake()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rigidBody.freezeRotation = true;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!jumping)
        {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown ("up")) {
                    rigidBody.AddForce (new Vector3 (0, uspeed, fspeed));
                }

                if (Input.GetButtonDown ("down")) {
                    rigidBody.AddForce (new Vector3 (0, uspeed, -fspeed));
                }

                if (Input.GetButtonDown ("right")) {
                    rigidBody.AddForce (new Vector3 (fspeed, uspeed, 0));
                }

                if (Input.GetButtonDown ("left")) {
                    rigidBody.AddForce (new Vector3 (-fspeed, uspeed, 0));
                }
         }

     }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        jumping = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        jumping = true;
    }                
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a timer or something onto the  rigidBody.AddForce (new Vector3 (0, uspeed, -fspeed)); ? it could be getting confused and never un registering that you are not pressing a key. Just a quick thought

Comment: Nice structure btw, nice to see your making your own character controller :), +1 for that

Answer (score 3):

Use a `ForceMode`. `Impulse` is great for a jumping character, looks realistic as uses mass. And it's not continuous. Also requires a lower value for more effect.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
   rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, uspeed, fspeed), ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Leaving the force mode parameter empty causes `Force` to be default as `ForceMode` which is continuous. Which causes sliding more than inertia does.

For ignoring inertial sliding nullify velocity when touching ground.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
    {
        jumping = false;

        rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }        
}
```

Checking `!jumping` before input already rules out jumping on air.